# how to pass data to ng2-smart-table renderComponent from http request?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I have a table with a custom component in a cell and a service that provides me some data to display.
My custom component implements select.
So, table's column looks like this:

```
userRole: {
title: 'User Role,
type: 'custom',
renderComponent: SelectComponent,
onComponentInitFunction: (instance) => {
instance.selectEdit
.subscribe( (data) => {
console.log(data);
});
}
  },
```

select.component.html:

```
<select #select
        (change)="callType(select.value)"
>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options"
          attr.value="option.id" >{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

select.component.ts:

```
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, ViewCell {
@Input() value: string | number;
@Input() rowData: any;
@Input() options;
@Output() selectEdit = new EventEmitter();

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {

}

callType(event) {
this.selectEdit.emit(event);
}

  }
```

Seems like `instance` object should have `options` property (because it's under `@Input`), but it doesn't :(
I've tried somethng like
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/521#issuecomment-333273103
but it doesn't work for me because I need data from Observable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tricky solution:**
prepare data for `SelectComponent` before render component with table.
container.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.httpAllRoles()
      .subscribe((roles: Role[]) => {
        this.roles = roles;
      });
  }
```

container.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="roles">
  <app-table [roles]="roles"></app-table>
</div>
```

then pass data to inner component through `valuePrepareFunction`
table.component.ts:

```
      userRole: {
        title: 'userRole,
        filter: false,
        type: 'custom',
        valuePrepareFunction: (value, row, cell) => {
          // DATA FROM HERE GOES TO renderComponent
          return this.roles;
        },
        renderComponent: SelectComponent,
        onComponentInitFunction: (instance) => {
          instance.selectEdit
            .subscribe( (data) => {
              console.log(data);
            });
        }
      },
```

to receive data in SelectComponent:

```
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit, ViewCell {
  @Input() value; // data from table
  @Input() rowData;
```